# Firestore billing on update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, billing

If I update a document with the same content as the existing one, will it count as a write even if it doesn't change anything to the current document's content?

In other words, does Firestore update the document without checking the values of each key inside the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I update a document with the same content as the existing one, will it count as a write even if it doesn't change anything to the current document's content?

Yes, it does.

> In other words, does Firestore update the document without checking the values of each key inside the document?

Yes, it does update, it overwrites the entire document, no matter if is the same or not. Firestore doesn't have a mechanism to check if the document is the same. You should check that out.